# ¿Como puedo resolver este ejercicio? C++ Ciclo for

Tags: c++, algoritmos, ciclos

comenze a programar con ciclo for, me ayudarian a intentar resolver este ejercicio? Gracias.. Elabore un programa que permita ingresar un numero entero del 1 al 12 y me muestre la tabla de multiplicar de dicho numero.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () {

    int n,contador=0,multiplicacion=0;

    printf("Ingrese un numero: ");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n>0 && n<=12)

    for(contador=0;contador<=10;contador++){

    multiplicacion=multiplicacion*n;

    contador++;
    }

    printf("la tabla de multiplicar es: %d ",multiplicacion);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado?

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir lo que lleves al cuerpo de la pregunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu quieres que te muestre la tabla... sin embargo no estás guardando los datos temporales:

```
for(contador=0;contador<=10;contador++){
  multiplicacion=multiplicacion*n; // <<---
  contador++;
}
```

La línea comentada machaca el valor almacenado en `multiplicacion` en cada iteración.

Si tu idea es mostrar cada resultado tienes que imprimir el resultado **en cada iteración**

```
for(int contador=0;contador<=10;contador++){
  int multiplicacion=contador*n;
  std::cout << multiplicacion << '\n'; // Estamos en C++
  contador++;
}
```

Si probamos el código vemos que hace cosas raras (si por ejemplo intentamos imprimir la tabla del 1...

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
```

¿Qué está pasando? Bien, fíjate en la última línea del `for`:

```
for(int contador=0;contador<=10;contador++){
  int multiplicacion=contador*n;
  std::cout << multiplicacion << '\n';
  contador++; // <<---
}
```

Estás incrementando el contador dos veces en cada iteración: en la propia declaración del `for` y en esa última línea. La solución es tan sencilla como eliminar ese segundo incremento:

```
for(int contador=0;contador<=10;contador++){
  int multiplicacion=contador*n;
  std::cout << multiplicacion << '\n';
}
```

Por cierto, `cout` se encuentra en la libreria `iostream`. El ejemplo con código más propio de C++ que de C quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  int n;

  std::cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
  std::cin >> n;

  std::cout << "la tabla de multiplicar es: \n";
  if(n>0 && n<=12)
  {
    for(int contador=0;contador<=10;contador++){
      int multiplicacion=contador*n;
      std::cout << n << 'x' << contador << '=' << multiplicacion << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! ahi lo acomode y me anduvo! :D

Comment: @GustavoTorres Piensa que para aprender no debes copiar la respuesta sino entenderla...en los examenes no vamos a estar ahí para responder por ti

Comment: estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta igual jaja gracias!

Comment: @GustavoTorres da igual... si te acostumbras a copiar no vas a aprender y te aviso que C++ puede ser bastante inhóspito si no se entiende

Comment: no copio, solo que estoy arrancando con este tema y necesito ver ejemplos y ayuda, me hace falta un empujon, luego ya no necesitare preguntar estas cosas

Comment: igual tienes razon..